# Get values from json string

Tags: php, json

I am extracting the values from JSON but keep getting an empty result when I echo the value

```
$json='[[{"transTime":"2013-10-23 17:30:42","Forename":"Ian","Surname":"Graham","Address Line 1":"RG412GX"}]]';

$obj2 = json_decode($json, true);

$displayName = $obj2->Surname;

echo"$displayName";
```

Comment: What's that `$xmlresponse`?

Comment: Is $xmlresponse supposed to be $json ? And where did the $value come from ?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What do you get when you do  a `print_r($obj2);`?

Comment: why are you decoding $xmlresponse instead of $json?

Answer (score 1):

you have one object in other one in this json string

```
$json='[[{"transTime":"2013-10-23 17:30:42","Forename":"Ian","Surname":"Graham","Address Line 1":"RG412GX"}]]';

$obj2 = json_decode($json);

print_r($obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json='[[{"transTime":"2013-10-23 17:30:42","Forename":"Ian","Surname":"Graham","Address Line 1":"RG412GX"}]]';
$obj2 = json_decode($json, true);
$displayName = $obj2[0][0]['Surname'];
echo "$displayName";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be something like:

```
$json='[[{"transTime":"2013-10-23 17:30:42","Forename":"Ian","Surname":"Graham","Address    Line 1":"RG412GX"}]]';

$obj2 = json_decode($json, true);

$displayName = $obj2->Surname;

echo"$displayName";
```

You are mixing up / making up variable names...

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code you provided.
First, your json text is stored in `$json`, but you try to decode `$xmlresponse`. I guess that's just a copy/paste error, though.
Second, you try to access the surname using the object syntax although you explicitly force `json_decode` to decode objects as associative arrays.
Third, the json provided encodes an object in an array in an array. You ignore the nested structure of the response.

Try this:

```
$json='[[{"transTime":"2013-10-23 17:30:42","Forename":"Ian","Surname":"Graham","Address Line 1":"RG412GX"}]]';
$response = json_decode($json);
$displayName = $response[0][0]->Surname;

echo $displayName;
```